# Генерация рандомных незанятых имен временных файлов

Tags: c++

Делаю сортировку слиянием. Надо разбить файл на кучу временных файлов и слить в 1 отсортированный файл. Но как называть новые файлы, да так, чтобы не хранить их имена в ОЗУ (файлов может быть очень много)?

Я решил создавать отдельную папку в `%temp%`, а в ней создавать файлы просто пронумерованные 0, 1, 2 и т.д. Но когда сливаю опять проблема появляется, когда беру 2 файла, мне надо создать 3 и туда записывать значения, а эти 2 удалить, но я не знаю как его назвать.

Есть ли способы генерации рандомных незанятых имен, кроме обычного рандома с проверкой на существования?

В идеале функцию в стандартной библиотеки, но я нашел только генерацию в `%temp%`, а не в конкретной папке. Я даже 100 названий сгенерировал ей, все 100 раз одинаковые дала, т.к. файл все еще не занят в той самой папке %temp%.

Comment: А что мешает создать файл со следующим номером?

Comment: Так в `cstdio` есть функции для генерации имен для временных файлов